# Is (current) residence status conditional to one's citizenship(s)?

Tags: resident-permit, citizenship, residency

Is a residence permit somehow "tied" to the citizenship you have/had when applying for and/or receiving said permit or is it legally independent of it? For example:

1. A person applies for and receives a residence permit for [Elbonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilbert#Elbonia) as a citizen of [Ruritania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruritania)
2. While residing in Elbonia, said person loses Ruritanian citizenship for whatever reason but

   - they (still) are not a citizen of Elbonia
   - they are not a citizen of any country for which Elbonia has a freedom-of-movement agreement (e.g. not like Spain with Malta, with both being in the EU)
3. Does the residence status of this person change?-- Do they have to re-apply for residence or somehow "change" their residence permit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this might depend on the countries involved, and there being examples for both cases

Comment: It depends on the immigration law of the country that granted the person's resident status and issued the residence permit. My guess is, in most cases, not reapply, but in some cases they may need to register their new status, which might be seen as "changing" the permit. As it is, I will vote to close the question as too broad.